# Rails 3.2 app - files to keep in/out of respository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, version-control

I am starting a Rails 3.2 application. I am using Git for my respository, and wanted to know which files I should keep versions of, and which files I should generate on the fly from command operations.

Specifically:

```
config/routes.rb
db/migrate/*  
db/schema.rb  
lib/assets/*  
lib/tasks/*  
script/rails
test/performance/browsing_test.rb  
tmp/*  
vendor/assests/*  
vendor/plugins/*
```

Any others I should be aware of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the list, everything except `tmp` has to or can be tracked in the repo.

See here for a standard .gitignore for Rails: https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Rails.gitignore

Once you add such a .gitignore to your repository, you can rest assured that files that need not be tracked and those that are generated are not added to your repository accidentally.

Comment: Ah, just beat me! I agree though, ignoring `routes.rb` would be crazy.

Answer (score 2):

This is our current .gitignore file:

```
!spec/javascripts/generated/lib
*.swo
*.swp
.DS_Store
.bundle
.project
.sass-cache/
config/*.sphinx.conf
config/database.yml
coverage/*
db/*.sqlite3
db/*.sqlite3-journal
db/sphinx
log/*
public/assets/
public/javascripts/compiled/*
spec/javascripts/generated/*
tmp/*
```